# Unexpected python behavior related to default argument for mutable object

Tags: python

```
#! /usr/bin/python

class my_class:
    # 1. __init__
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_set = set()

    # 2. __init__
    #def __init__(self, arg_set = set()):
    #    self.my_set = arg_set 

c1 = my_class()
c1.my_set.add('a')

print c1.my_set

c2 = my_class()
c2.my_set.add('b')

print c1.my_set
```

my_class has 2 ways of defining `__init__`:

If I use 1st way, output is as expected:
    `set(['a'])`
    `set(['a'])`

If I use 2nd way, output is unexpected:
    `set(['a'])`
    `set(['a', 'b'])`

What is wrong with 2nd way? How can modification of C2 (a separate object), result in modification of c1?

`Edit: Updated the question title to reflect specific area of concern`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument, I believe

Comment: @Haidro. Thanks for the link. It has very good information on this behavior. For me the learning is - "Avoid default parameter value for mutable objects unless you know what you are doing"

Comment: Pretty much. Just be aware on the outputs, and check out [egor's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19809778/1971805) answer on a great solution around it. It's very helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

> Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is
>   executed. This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the
>   function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used
>   for each call. This is especially important to understand when a
>   default parameter is a mutable object, such as a list or a dictionary:
>   if the function modifies the object (e.g. by appending an item to a
>   list), the default value is in effect modified.

Thats the reason why your second method appends values everytime.

Moreover, modify the second `__init__` like this

```
def __init__(self, arg_set = set()):
   print id(arg_set)
   self.my_set = arg_set
```

Now, when you run the code, you ll always get the same address (`id` function in CPython returns the address of the object in memory). **So, default arguments are not created everytime the function is invoked, but when evaluated the first time.**

Comment: Thanks. This was driving me nuts! The SO link posted by Haidro has some interesting explanantions.

Answer (score 1):

thefourtheye is completely right on the cause of this behavior. If you want to use the second version of your constructor, it should be like this:

```
def __init__(self, arg_set=None):
    if arg_set is None:
        self.my_set = set()
    else:
        self.my_set = arg_set
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach.